# Databinding ListView in Xamarin.Forms does not seem to work in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class SelectClientPage : ContentPage
{
    public SelectClientPage(ClientResult[] clients)
    {
        this.BindingContext = new SelectClientViewModel(this, clients);

        var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = 20 };

        var list = new ListView
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ClientListTemplate)),
            BackgroundColor = MobileColor.LightOrigamiBlue.ToFormsColor(),
            HasUnevenRows = true,
        };
        list.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Clients");
        list.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedItemProperty, "SelectedItem");

        layout.Children.Add(list);

        this.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        this.Content = layout;
    }

    public class ClientListTemplate : ViewCell
    {
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            ClientResult client = (ClientResult)this.BindingContext;
            var pad = new ContentView {
                Padding = new Thickness(5,5),
                Content = new Label 
                { 
                    Text = client.name,
                    TextColor = Color.White,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(ListView))
                }
            };
            this.View = pad;
        }
    }
}

public class SelectClientViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SelectClientViewModel(Page page, ClientResult[] clients) : base(page)
    {
        this._Clients = clients;
    }

    private ClientResult[] _Clients;
    public ClientResult[] Clients { get { return _Clients; } }

    private object _SelectedItem = null;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref _SelectedItem, value); }
    }

    //... rest truncated //
}
```

This code works fine in iOS or Android.  However, in UWP, it fails in this line in the ClientListTemplate class:

```
ClientResult client = (ClientResult)this.BindingContext;
```

The reason it fails is because the BindingContext passed in to the ViewCell is of type SelectClientViewModel, which was assigned to the BindingContext of the content page initially.  So it throws an Invalid Cast Exception.

Has anybody else encountered this?  I'm on Xamarin.Forms v2.3.3.175.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more code about `SelectClientViewModel`.

Comment: Nico, I added it.  There isn't much to it.  Anyways, I contacted Xamarin support and they confirmed that there is a bug in UWP and opened a ticket for me:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51210